# One way Synchronize 2 Access Tables with VBA ADODB

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, adodb

I am synchronizing two MS-Access databases.
One of them on a network drive, the other one on the local machine.
(For testing purposes both in the same directory)

The Databases both contain a table named "tblCheckup" with an essential ID Field called "checkGUID"

I am aware that this will probably fail if there are no records in either of the Tables but this is of no concern.

Since i am fairly new to ADODB and MS Access i am looking for any performance issues with larger scales. Expected table size growth is around 3000 entries per year.

I am thankful for any hints concerning possible runtime errors, possible bottlenecks in speed and performance issues in larger scales as stated above. Also i am not really sure if i used the best CursorType and LockType.

```
Private Sub SyncToServerTest()
Dim rsExists As Boolean
Dim lngCount As Long

Dim connLokal As ADODB.Connection
Dim connServer As ADODB.Connection
Dim dataLokal As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dataServer As ADODB.Recordset

Set connLokal = New ADODB.Connection
Set connServer = New ADODB.Connection
Set dataLokal = New ADODB.Recordset
Set dataServer = New ADODB.Recordset

connLokal.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\AccessSyncTest\Lokal.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
connLokal.Open
connServer.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\AccessSyncTest\Server.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
connServer.Open

With dataLokal
    .ActiveConnection = connLokal
    .Source = "tblCheckup"
    .LockType = adLockPessimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .Open
    
    If .EOF Then
        Debug.Print "No entries in Local Table"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        .MoveFirst
    End If
    
End With

With dataServer
    .ActiveConnection = connServer
    .Source = "tblCheckup"
    .LockType = adLockPessimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .Open
    
    If .EOF Then
        Debug.Print "No entries in Server Table"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        .MoveFirst
    End If
End With

Do Until dataLokal.EOF
    rsExists = False
    Do Until dataServer.EOF Or rsExists
        If dataLokal.Fields("checkGUID").Value = dataServer.Fields("checkGUID").Value Then
            rsExists = True
        End If
        dataServer.MoveNext
    Loop
    If Not rsExists Then
        dataServer.AddNew
         For lngCount = 0 To dataLokal.Fields.Count - 1
            dataServer.Fields(dataLokal.Fields(lngCount).Name).Value = dataLokal.Fields(lngCount).Value
        Next lngCount
        Debug.Print dataLokal.Fields("checkGUID").Value & " was added"
        
    End If
    dataServer.MoveFirst
    dataLokal.MoveNext
Loop

dataLokal.Close
dataServer.Close

Set dataLokal = Nothing
Set dataServer = Nothing
Set connLokal = Nothing
Set connServer = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Using nested while loops can easily turn into a time-sink. Rather, save the missing checkGUID values to an array using SQL, and only loop once to save time (and debugging headaches):

```
Dim r As Object, sqlSTR As String, i As Long, guids As Variant

' only grab checkGUID values which exist in dataLocal but not dataServer
sqlSTR = "SELECT dataLokal.checkGUID" _
& " FROM dataLokal LEFT JOIN dataServer ON dataLokal.checkGUID = dataServer.checkGUID " _
& " WHERE dataServer.checkGUID Is Null"

Set r = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlSTR, adOpenDynamic)

With r
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    guids = .GetRows(.RecordCount)
End With
r.Close
Set r = Nothing

For i = 0 To UBound(guids, 2)
    updateGUID = guids(0,i)
    ' ... table updates by updateGUID value'
Next i
```

Comment: Thats clever, thank you. Exactly what i was hoping for. I feel like learning more SQL is the way to improve here.  COuld you explain why you use adOpenDynamic? I thought i could use Forwardonly and improve performance this way.